# How to use the baked in validator "hostname_port" from go-playground/validator?

Tags: go

I want to validate a configured port using the [go validator](https://github.com/go-playground/validator) package. I tried the following sample code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"

    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    config := New()
    err := config.Validate()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

        return
    }

    fmt.Println(config.Port)
}

type Configuration struct {
    Port int `validate:"hostname_port"`
}

func New() Configuration {
    return Configuration{
        Port: 8080,
    }
}

func (c Configuration) Validate() error {
    validator := validator.New()

    return validator.Struct(c)
}
```

Unfortunately I get the error

> Key: 'Configuration.Port' Error:Field validation for 'Port' failed on the 'hostname_port' tag

I got it working by changing the type to a string and passing in `":8080"`. I prefer using an integer ( better uint ), are there any solutions for this or should I use a custom validation like `validate:"gte=1,lte=65535"`?

Comment: `hostname_port` "validates a <dns>:<port> combination for fields typically used for socket address" (so, as you found, an integer is invalid, but `127.0.0.1:8080` would be valid and will not work with an `Port int`!). As you are just storing a port a custom validator is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "`validate:"number,gte=0,lte=65535"`" tag could work?

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type Configuration struct {
    Port int `validate:"number,gte=0,lte=65535"`
}

func TestV(t *testing.T) {

    c := Configuration{
        Port: 200000,
    }
    validator := validator.New()

    assert.NoError(t, validator.Struct(c))

}
```

Also, just try `uint16` type for the `Port` field.

But I would recommend sticking with the hostname_port pattern in configs. This would make your configuration seamlessly fit with most of the other go-libs.